# How to properly convert a string "3/6/2019 3:40:19 PM" to a Laravel/Eloquent datetime type?

Tags: php, datetime, laravel-5

I have a string "3/6/2019 3:40:19 PM" that I want to convert to a Laravel/Eloquent datetime type.

Is there a way to do that without retrieve all small pieces of the string and rebuild again to the desired format?

Comment: Can you share more details? In which parts of your code do you want to run such transformation?

Comment: Is `3/6` March 6th or June 3rd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line solution:

`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('3/6/2019 3:40:19 PM')));`

If you want to use Laravel's Carbon you can take a look at the [api docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/):
I've found an example similar to your situation that also parses the 'pm'

```
$date = Carbon::createFromIsoFormat('!YYYY-MMMM-D h:mm:ss a', '2019-January-3 6:33:24 pm', 'UTC');
echo $date->isoFormat('M/D/YY HH:mm'); // 1/3/19 18:33
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Carbon, which is already part of any Laravel install.

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters

If you have a datetime string and you want to use it with a `Carbon` instance you can do:

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('j/n/Y g:i:s A', '3/6/2019 3:40:19 PM');
```

Then you can do something like:

```
$date->format('Y-m-d')
$date->format('H:i:s')
```

Comment: If the strings he gets is "3/6/2019 3:40:19 PM" you are kinda cheating by tuning it to "2016-11-01 15:04:19"

Comment: @RiccardoCedrola Yeah. Carbon's `createFromFormat` will help here. I edited that in.

Comment: Using carbon Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Trailing data -  ..  This i sthe code $date = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:s','3/6/2019 3:40:19 PM');

Comment: @zwitterion Your format is not `Y-m-d H:m:s`. I gave the correct format (and exact code that works for your specific date/time string) in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP `strtotime()` function.
`strToTime($string)`

And if you want to change the format you can use the `date()` function.
`date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($string))`

This saves you the hassle of installing new libraries and you can change the date format in any way you want in the date function

Comment: you need to put `H:i:s` instead of `h:i:s`, otherwise`strtotime()` doesn't parse the 'PM'

Comment: Ahh yes thank you for pointing it out @RiccardoCedrola i missed it

Comment: Upvoted you anyways, you answer is correct for me :)

Comment: `strtotime` **may** generate the wrong date, though, as OP's 3/6 could be March 6 or June 3, depending on country. As for "new libraries", Laravel includes Carbon as a core component.

Comment: I agree, it's always safer to define the format of the date you are passing as string, so the use of `DateTime::createFromFormat` or also `Carbon::createFromFormat` it's always safer, But I think that he could easily figure it out by looking at the docs, without anyone giving him "ready code"

Comment: And yes guys what you are saying is true. I believe i take these things for granted now that i use things like Carbon and such.